# WAMP Server :Project not running on localhost

Tags: php, apache, xampp, wamp, port

I have installed WampServer Version 2.4.9 on windows 7

Created a folder in wamp/www/myproject/index.php ,I am using user account(not admin account).The index.php conatins HTML code only,I tried with index.html too,but nothing worked.

The problem:

When I run localhost or phpmy admin by typing localhost in browser URL space then it shows the main window and then i click on project and get these messages:

```
This webpage is not available
```

when I click on more button in browser

> The server at myproject can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to
>   its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no
>   connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be
>   caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google
>   Chrome from accessing the network.

I tried running from admin account too but that also did not worked.I tried running the application with off state of firewall too but that also did not work

EDIT:
I uninstalled xxamp ,I have apache tomcat too in my system that is used with JSP ,it takes 8080 port.but it is not running currently.The default port for wamp is 80,I tried running it on 81,8080,but both the thing didn't work.Skype also take port 80 so I exited from skype too...

**when i type localhost/myproject,It worked.**

but when I type localhost and then main page of wamp comes...and when click on localhost then the dns lookup failure occur that is written initially

Comment: did you started the wamp server ?

Comment: yes,the localhost window is coming...

Comment: Check if you have multiple wampp in system(in different directories)...

Comment: I have xxamp in d: drive and wamp in c: drive

Comment: what ports are xxampp and wamp listening to?

Comment: Shall i uninstall xxamp for running wamp.?or their is any other way?

Comment: both are listening on port 80

Comment: try changing wamp to 8080, and then try testing the wamp server with localhost:8080. Does it work then?

Comment: shall i change the ports for my wamp server..and if i change ...which port should i use?

Comment: btw, I forgot to mention that after changing the port to 8080, you'll need to restart the service.

Comment: the port number is already 8080,8080 is default port for all server,right?I have a separate tomcat apache also installed for running JSP in c drive...that is also occupying the same port.But currently I have not started any other server like xampp and tomcat apache.Only wamp is started.

Comment: I was hoping it was the port... have you added any url to the hosts file? are you browsing directly to `http://localhost` or are you using something as `http://myproject`?

Comment: I am using http://localhost directly....I have not added url

Comment: If you have 2 other Apache servers on your system, does that mean you also have 2 other MYSQL servers also, I know XAMPP comes with one but I am not sure about Tomcat.

Comment: What happens when you use this url `localhost/myproject`

Comment: The tomcat is installed separatly..for using with JSP

Comment: but when I type localhost and then main page of wamp comes...and when click on localhost then the dns lookup failure occur

Comment: Hey It worked when I put the url like localhost/myproject...but still I am not able to figure it out that why it is not working other way

Answer (score 0):

check whether port 80 is free. You can check it in your apache conf file.

Comment: I ran netstat -anb command and tjhere is no local address having port 80.I think my system is able to take port other wise the main page of wamp server itself shouldn't come.I am not sure about it.Please guide me if possible...